# Очень много ошибок в Unity после переноса на другой PC

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть успешно работающий проект на одном PC, скопировали его целиком на второй, после реимпорта получили 328 ошибок. Удалили папку Library, снова реимпорт, снова 328 ошибок.

Все ошибки исключительно такие

```
The type or namespace "x" could not be found. Are you missing an assembly 
reference?

The type or namespace "x" could not be found. Are you missing "y" using 
directive?
```

x и y самые разные. Проект естественно не компилируется.

Unity 5.6
Есть те кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Настройки проекта Profile framework надо посмотреть чтоб совпали... может из-за этого..... зайти в VS и установить такой же как на другом

Comment: Попробуйте скопируйте только папки Assets и ProjectSettings

Comment: Папка Library никак не влияет на ошибки такого типа. У вас скорей всего dll plugin(или несколько), который отключился при переносе, отсюда он не видит namespace, чтобы Unity снова увидел plugin, его нужно перенести в папку Plugins, нажать ReImport, и тогда можно переносить обратно в любую папку, ну или оставить тут же.